# npm install giving npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, solidity, visual-studio-code-server

When I run npm install, I am getting the error message
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Node --version : v20.8.0
Npm --version : 8.13.1

Tried multiple other commands
npm i --package-lock-only
npm intsall --force
npm clear --cache and npm install

but still the same error

Log file generated by npm install is displaying following set of events:
6839 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
6839 verbose stack     at Function.keys ()
6839 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\lib\index.js:213:22)
6839 verbose stack     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:125:22)
6839 verbose stack     at async [nodeFromEdge] (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1108:19)
6839 verbose stack     at async [buildDepStep] (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:976:11)
6839 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
6839 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
6839 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:153:5)
6839 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:145:5)
6839 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\saniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)

Any advise on this will be appreciated.

I was trying to generate package-jason.lock and node_modules folder for solidity.

Comment: This specific issue got resolved after I downgraded from Node:20.8.0 to Node:18.18.0.